# Meteor parsing a list of arrays with forEach

Tags: meteor, foreach

I have this helper in Meteor:

```
itemMenuAddOns: function(_id){
        console.log(_id); //OK
        var addOns = RestMenuItems.find({_id:_id}, {addOns: 1});
        if(addOns){
            console.log(addOns); //OK, an object where in the collection/map I see the expected array.   
            addOns.forEach( function(addOn) { console.log(addOn.title); } )// displays nothing
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the forEach console.log displays nothing. In both cases, if I use  addOn.title or just even 123, to display.
thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the `addOns` array is that is referenced by the `addOns` variable is what you think it is? The result of your query should be an array of objects with the `_id` and `addOns` properties. When iterating the array, the `addOn` you get is one of those objects, and therefore has no `title` property.

Comment: Inside the curser I have collection/docs/map and there a list of objects. each object has a key and a few pairs of key/values. Maybe what I need is a "map" method to get the data?  
map: Object
2WrjMzM2iGvh5pw5p: Object  
ByoaJFGBwzYJ53u45: Object

Comment: Look more closely. Try to log `addOn` itself inside the `forEach()` call and see what you get. your `var addOns` references a database cursor.

Comment: I guess I am expecting to get only the addOns but I am getting the whole object...

Comment: Yes, you can use `map()` in order to only get the `addOns` values, but if `addOns` itself is an array (as I suspect it is), you will get an array of arrays. Since you query by `_id`, after mapping you will get an array with a single element, which is an array (the original `addOns` property of the record with the matching `_id`.

Comment: I was passing the wrong id.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had passed a wrong id and used find instead of findOne.
Now it works. for anyone interested:

```
itemMenuAddOns: function(_id){
       var list = '';
        var cursor = RestMenuItems.findOne({_id:_id}, {addOns: 1});
        if(cursor){
            cursor.addOns.forEach( function(addOn) {
                var addOn = RestMenuSideItems.findOne({_id: addOn});
                list += Spacebars.SafeString("<div>" + addOn.title + "</div>")});
            return list;
        }
    }
```